# Save NSAttributedString as rtfd in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, textkit

I'm trying to implement a text editor in iOS. It supports basic styles and is able to embed an image. For testing, I created a .rtfd file in Xcode like this:

[image]

Here is part of my code:

```
        // Create a text storage object and add it to the layout manager
        self.textStorage = NSTextStorage()
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let container = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize())
        container.widthTracksTextView = true
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(container)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        
        editorView = UITextView(frame: self.view.bounds, textContainer: container)
        editorView.isEditable = true
        editorView.isSelectable = true
        editorView.isScrollEnabled = true
        editorView.delegate = self
        
        // read from rtf file
        if let docURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "rtfd") {
            do {
                try textStorage?.read(from: docURL, documentAttributes: nil)
                print("Read rtfd file")
            } catch {
                // Could not read menu content.
                print("error")
            }
        }
        
        self.view.addSubview(editorView)
```

I have no problem to load this `rtfd` file and show it in my `UITextView`. But when I try to save in the following code, it failed:

```
        guard let rtfData = try? textStorage.data(from: NSMakeRange(0, textStorage.length), documentAttributes: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtfd]) else {
            print("Failed to convert attributed string to RTFD data")
            return
        }

        // Write the RTF data to a file
        let fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appending(path: "file.rtfd")
        do {
            try rtfData.write(to: fileURL)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to write RTF data to file: \(error)")
        }
```

The file has been saved but can't open it. It's a garbage. But when I changed it to `rtf`, there is no issue to save. But the image disappears.

By the way, there is a function called `rtfd(from:` in `NSTextStorage`. But I can't use it in iOS.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Where do you read it exactly? It's unclear because you read at `Bundle.main`, but save elsewhere (it's norma, you can't override the bundle), but you don't read what you've saved? Also `documentAttributes: nil)` shouldn't you specifiy that's an RTFD there?

Comment: @Larme I created by Xcode and add it to the `Bundle.main`. Then save it to document folder after editing.

Comment: You say that the error is about reading the saved file in DocumentsDirectory, where do you read it froom there? What's the code?

Comment: @Larme There is no error message to save and read. But the data is garbage.